# Shared element transition leaves a strange white background between first activity and second transparent activity

Tags: android, transparent, shared-element-transition

Recently I faced up with a weird problem.
I have two activities. The first one contains a grid with a thumbnails. A kind of a gallery. And the second one contains a view pager with fragments and behaves like an image viewer where you can slide between images. 
I use a shared element transition to start the second activity. Just like Google Photo app. On the second activity I can swipe to top or bottom to dismiss the activity with a fade away transition of the background. I made my second activity fully transparent:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/palette_transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
```

But the problem is when I swipe an image to top/bottom and the second activity's background fades I can see a white background but not the first activity. If I start the second activity without shared element transition everything is fine.

I made a research and found out that this white layer probably overlays the first activity. It is not a part of the second activity as I can see in Stetho view hierarchy.

Probably my explanation is not very good neither my English language so here a couple of videos too clarify my problem.

Video [Without transition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSfa9TgpHCk) and Video [With transition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RACj8tgTMqI)

Comment: Did you solve this? im just having same issue

Comment: @nsL Yes. The problem was with windowEnterTransition and windowExitTransition attributes in our theme. We just removed them and white blink is gone.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Will you please help me by sharing your style, please. And I haven't added any entry or exit transitions as well.

Comment: @GuruKarthiR please check my answer.

Comment: Ya, I have tried that too. But it doesn't work out well as expected. @ArtyomShalaev

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```xml
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item>
```